refreshing Listview in MAUI
Holla!
I have created a MAUI android Project and one page is designed sofar like shown below

the xaml behind the table shown at the buttom is simply a gridview with three Listview
 <Grid x:Name="GridBill" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0.5,1,0.2">

 <ListView x:Name="ListInvoice"
 BackgroundColor="Bisque"
 SeparatorColor="Silver"
 Grid.Column="0">

     <ListView.Header>
         <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
             <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
             Text="{x:Static lang:AppResources.ItemName}"
             FontSize="12"
             FontAttributes="Bold" />
         </StackLayout>
     </ListView.Header>

     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                 <Label x:Name="NameLabel"  Text="{Binding Name}"/>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>


 <ListView x:Name="ListInvoice2"
 BackgroundColor="Bisque"
 SeparatorColor="Silver"
 Grid.Column="1">

     <ListView.Header>
         <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
             <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
             Text="{x:Static lang:AppResources.Price}"
             FontSize="12"
             FontAttributes="Bold" />
         </StackLayout>
     </ListView.Header>

     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                 <Label Text="{Binding Price}"/>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>


 <ListView x:Name="ListInvoice3"
  BackgroundColor="Bisque"
  SeparatorColor="Silver"
  Grid.Column="2">

     <ListView.Header>
         <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
             <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
              Text="{x:Static lang:AppResources.Count}"
              FontSize="12"
              FontAttributes="Bold" />
         </StackLayout>
     </ListView.Header>

     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                 <Label Text="{Binding Count}"/>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>

in the page page.xaml.cs I created an internal class and a list of it as shown below
public partial class Sailor : ContentPage
{
List<CollectionItem> items;

internal class CollectionItem
{   public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
}

 public Sailor()
 {
 InitializeComponent();
 items = new List<CollectionItem>
     {
         new CollectionItem{ Name = "xx", Count = "2", Price = "10" },
         new CollectionItem{ Name = "zz", Count = "2", Price = "10" }
     };


    ListInvoice.ItemsSource = items;
    ListInvoice2.ItemsSource = items;
    ListInvoice3.ItemsSource = items;

}

I built some logic; when Barcode is detected I quest a SQLite DB and get Artice_name and Price and I can print them out when I use console.writeline
Now inorder to add the quested Info in the list view I used this code:
private void CameraView_OnDetectionFinished(object sender, OnDetectionFinishedEventArg e)
{
            //play peep
            
            //search in DB
            string returnedName = "";
            string returnedPrice = "";

            var items = await database.GetItemAsync(scannedBarcode);
            
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("################");
                returnedName = item.Art_Name;
                returnedPrice = item.Art_Price.ToString();
            }


            //add new item to the list
            CollectionItem boughtItem = new CollectionItem { Name = returnedName, Count = "1", Price = returnedPrice };

            Console.WriteLine(returnedName);
            Console.WriteLine(returnedPrice);

            Console.WriteLine(boughtItem.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(boughtItem.Price);

            this.items.Add(boughtItem);
            ListInvoice.ItemsSource = items;
            ListInvoice2.ItemsSource = items;
            ListInvoice3.ItemsSource = items;

        });

    }

}

}
The issue is, when I scann a barcode and its matching in DB, my code does not update the view list correctely, Nothing happens in xaml UI!
this is the Output from the VS debugger:

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, probably some issue with binding? could you please advice how to refresh the list view sothat it shows the new items each time the list got updated
Cheers! : )

use ObservableCollection instead of List

thnx @Jason , you solved it : )
